# How to change the default desktop icon size?

Tags: 11.10, icons, resize

How to change the size of desktop icons? I tried gconf-editor as given at [How to change desktop icon size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83099/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size) .

I am not getting the option for changing size at `app > nautilus > icon_view`.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. Kindly help me in changing default icon size.

I want to make them small.

Comment: I found this while experiencing a problem with updating to a newer version of nautilus, and [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/689839/109484) did the trick for me

Answer (score 10):

Right click on the icon, and then you will see an option to resize the icon. At least, in 12.04 it works.

For changing the default icon size:
In Nautilus (eg your personal folder) > Edit > Preference > tab Views > under Icon View Default change the Default Zoom level.

But this change the size of all the icons inside Nautilus.

But in Nautilus you can change the icon size in a particular folder by View > Zoom in, to get the normal size of the icon in that folder, and this will be remembered after a restart.

Answer (score 4):

-- Open file explorer
-- Edit > Preperences > Icon View Defaults

Set as you wish.

[image: How to change the default desktop icon size?]