# How to resize the icons of the desktop?

Tags: 14.04, icons, desktop-environments

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 & I need to decrease all the icons size in one move, can I do it or I must resize each icon?

Comment: For Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome Flashback: 
Go to Files (file manager app), go to the Desktop folder, hold control + scroll mouse wheel. This changes the sizes in both the window and on the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on your desktop, click on Desktop Settings. There you should have 3 tabs: Background, Menus, and Icons. CLick on Icons and you should see Icon size. Adjust Icon size accordingly.

Comment: There's no Desktop Settings to click on, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: From this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/129820/how-to-change-the-default-desktop-icon-size. -- Open file explorer
-- Edit > Preperences > Icon View Defaults

Set as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

The comment above gives the correct answer:

From this answer: askubuntu.com/questions/129820/…. -- Open file explorer --  Edit > Preferences > Icon View Defaults Set as you wish. – md_essam

Answer (score 0):

For the file manager in Ubuntu 16.04 you use scroll wheel and crtl in the file manager, only it does not get any smaller than 32 pt.

Comment: The question refers to Ubuntu 14.04, not 16.04.