# Icon size/spacing settings for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: preferences

The last update like from yesterday has weirded out my desktop - icon spacing very wide, icons large, etc. - some of the icons were completely off the screen and had to use right click and "select all" to move them into view...

There used to be some place that you could tell it icon spacing/size, but it seems to be missing.-How do we adjust the desktop icon spacing / grid and/or icon size (other than 'resize' each one individually)?

Curious that I can login as my laptop's other user, and the icons are all just as they were - aligned in a tight grid/column and small. Not affected by whatever corrupted the other user desktop. Still, wonder how to edit these settings...

Comment: Could you post screenshot(s) of the current situation?

Comment: Oops - since things were 'off the screen' and I used 'select all' to move them back into the displayed area it's too late to 'see' that... and I resized every icon manually to its smallest and cut off 'keep aligned' so it will ignore the grid/column spacing and regrouped them as before this 'INCIDENT' so it all looks back as 'normal', don't see what a screen shot would give anyone. Really - just need info on how to make all the icons small/med/lg and to set the spacing distances between icons like before.... still need a 'SCREEN SHOT'?

Comment: Not necessary, but it helps, like the old clichéd saying "a picture is worth a thousand words". Not everyone has the adequate skill to make sense out of [a wall of text full of incoherent words](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1014373/1).

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 17.04 (and 17.10) with Gnome Flashback: Go to Files (file manager app), go to the Desktop folder, hold control + scroll mouse wheel. This changes the sizes in both the window and on the desktop.
original answer from: Ondra Žižka Jun 27 '17 at 14:10 at
[How to resize the icons of the desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720054/how-to-resize-the-icons-of-the-desktop)
(added the 17.10 part...)