# Custom desktop icon size

Tags: nautilus, customization

How do I change the Unity's desktop icon size to a custom value?

If I go to `Folder view > Edit > Preferences > Icon view > Default zoom lv` I can change the size between 400%, 200%, 150%, 100%, 66%, 50% and 33%.

But I would like a size in between 100% and 66%, maybe a 80% e.g.

Is possible to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change desktop icon size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83099/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size)