# Desktop icons default zoom level change regularly from 'small' to 'large'

Tags: nautilus, icons, 16.10, dconf, zooming

My question is directly related to [How to change desktop icon size?](https://askubuntu.com/q/83099/458410) and [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/83105/458410).

Desktop icons zoom level randomly keep changing :

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/nautilus/icon-view/default-zoom-level 
'large'
```

After changing value back to `'small'` with `dconf-editor`, everything is back to normal for a while before it happens again with no obvious reason.

Answer (score 2):

I had this as well, and found out that it's not randomly. The icons zoom with the last used view in Nautilus. I think the desktop icon size should be made independent from the nautilus icon size.