# How do I scale the enormously sized desktop icons on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, icons

I just upgraded to 18.04 (with GNOME 3.28) from 16.04. I am using `gnome-shell`, `gnome-ubuntu-desktop`. After upgrading the icon size on desktop are very large.

[image: icon size]

I am unable to find my option to decrease the size in preferences. How do I decrease it?

Comment: Best answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/118672/327339

Comment: @GabrielStaples I believe the option has been moved from there at least for Nautilus 3.26.4 which is the default file manager in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

1. Open Files (aka Nautilus)
2. **Grid view**: Change your icon view from "list" to "grid" first by clicking the button next to the hamburger menu.

   [image: screenshot]
3. **Zoom out**: Click on the hamburger menu (three-horizontal-lined button at top-right) and decrease the icon size by clicking the "zoom out" button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>).

This should also reduce the size of the icons in your desktop.

Comment: This is so silly, yet so useful. Thank you :) :) 
Tried so many cumbersome methods and this one finally worked.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the range ? I like to have more than the displayed limit. 50% .. 133%

Comment: Agree, this is silly. And not very intuitive.

Answer (score 9):

You can also resize icons by right clicking on each icons and select resize. Then you resize it up to a certain allowed minimum.

Comment: Neat... even though this answer doesn't really help the OP's issue as well as the accepted answer, I really like this feature.

Answer (score 9):

**In case you have a wheel mouse**

Open Nautilus and click on the show directory as symbols icon (**middle** of the button on the top-right of nautilus's window) an press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>**+Scroll Mouse up/down**.

Comment: Thank you! ... how to disable that keybinding?