# How can I resize the desktop icons in Ubuntu 19.04 like how it works in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: icons, resize

How can I resize the icons independently of each other?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4YecBMec6E&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/q/1030016/816190

Comment: @CharlesGreen the question you link to is simmilar but in ubuntu19.04 the solution is implemented in the settings so the answer is spesific for this  flavour of ubuntu.

Comment: @trondhansen I believe that this difference we are talking about is the desktop icons vs the icons in the dock.  Your answer refers to the dock (and dash) icons,  and the desktop icons are a separate item.  Regardless, the method I mentioned in the possible duplicate no longer works!

Comment: my answer below is for the desktop icons not for the size of the different folders and pictures in them they are still changed from the hamburger menu.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 19.04 you simply Open settings and go to dock there you will find a slider,Moving this changes the icon size.

This is one of the changes from previous versions of ubuntu

at 3,02 you can see how it is done https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbbPYdpdMb8

edit.
the question have been changed so this answer does only answer how to resize all of the desktop icons at once.

Comment: I can't find the tools.where can I find the tools? I don't mean that resizing the dock.

Comment: it is in settings there you will find dock and the slider to resize the icons.i did say wrong i am not an english native sorry for confusing you.i have edited my answer.

Comment: I feel sorry that I can't set the size of each icon differently. Thank you very much for your help. I think I'll have to stick for 16.04.

Comment: @LoveCherryMotion if you edit your question and add how to resize the icons independently of each other you will probably get higher quality answers.the better information you give the better an answer will be.