# Ubuntu 18.04 gnome desktop: all icons, font for all application is very small

Tags: gnome, icons, fonts, ubuntu-gnome

In my newly installed ubuntu 18.04 I have all the icons and fonts for all applications are extremely small. For example, below is a screenshot from my pinta application, tools section I can hardly see whats in there. How can I make it normal for all applications.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I scale the enormously sized desktop icons on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030016/how-do-i-scale-the-enormously-sized-desktop-icons-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @User24601 not at all related! This is a HighDPI issue, where GTK2 applications do not play well.

Comment: Provide information on your screen resolution. Also indicate precisely which applications are affected, and which not. My guess is that you are having a high resolution display. Depending on the toolkit of the application, it may not play well on HighDPI displays.

Answer (score 0):

You may use (GNOME) Tweaks to adjust font sizes of various elements.
First install Tweaks by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

(or sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool).

Then launch Tweaks and go to the **Fonts section**, you'll get the options to change font sizes.

[Check the answer in details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035520/how-do-i-increase-the-font-size-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-for-a-hdpi-4k-display#1035521)